# Is okay to use so much NEW statement?

Tags: java-8

I have this code that handles my commands:

```
public class CommandHandler {

    public static final CommandParser parser = new CommandParser();
    public static HashMap<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();

    public static void handleCommand(CommandParser.CommandContainer cmd) {

        if (commands.containsKey(cmd.invoke)) {         
            commands.get(cmd.invoke).action(cmd.event, cmd.args);
            commands.get(cmd.invoke).postAction(cmd.event, cmd.args);
        }
        /* else
            System.err.println("CMD NOT EXIST!"); */
    }
}

public static HashMap<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();

private static void addCommands() {
    commands.put(new cmdConfig().getCommand(), new cmdConfig());
    commands.put(new cmdHelp().getCommand(), new cmdHelp());
    commands.put(new cmdPing().getCommand(), new cmdPing());
}
```

This is a short code, but I have 157 commands.
Each command extends from an interface who has this methods:

```
public interface Command {
    public String getCommand();
    public String help();
    public void action(String[] args);
    public void postAction(String[] args);
}
```

Also, I use this code too:

```
String input = "random";

if (new cmdPing().getCommand().equals(input)) {
    new cmdPing().help();
}
else if (new cmdConfig().getCommand().equals(input)) {
    new cmdConfig().help();
}
else {
    printError(input + " is not a valid command");
}
```

and  I want to know if is okay to use to many NEW statements when i use `commands.put`and inside of `if()` statements too.

Comment: What else is in the command classes apart from the strings returned by the two accessor methods and the (I assume) common impl of `action()`?

Comment: Looks like your design is broken. `put(new cmdConfig().getCommand(), new cmdConfig())` should at least be written like `c = new cmdConfig(); put(c.getCommand(), c)`. Looks like you are creating many objects just to get a constant string, create a final static field in the class...

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s very weird that you are creating a `HashMap<String, Command> commands` containing all commands and then, not using that map to look up the commands, which is the very purpose of creating such a map.

```
public static final List<Command> ALL_COMMANDS
    = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
        new cmdConfig(), new cmdHelp(), new cmdPing(), …
    ));
public static Map<String, Command> ALL_COMMANDS_BY_NAME
    = ALL_COMMANDS.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Command::getCommand, Function.identity()));
```

```
String input = "random";
Command cmd = ALL_COMMANDS_BY_NAME.get(input);
if(cmd != null) cmd.help();
else printError(input + " is not a valid command");
```

If the actual implementations of the individual commands is rather short, you may consider implementing all of them in a single `enum` implementing `Command`. Then, you get the linear `ALL_COMMANDS` list for free, due to the generated `values()` method returning an array of all constants. The rest of the application logic stays the same.

Comment: I forgot to add the CommandHandler  class, you can check it out now.
I need a string key in hashmap, so enum doesn't work for me.

Comment: Also, i just tried it and it works perfectly. It was just what I needed.
If you encounter some other error in my code, please tell me.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Delete the interface and all implementing classes.

Instead, make `Command` an `enum` with `final` fields for `command` and `help`, a getter for help, and the `action()` method.

No need to have a getter for the command name, as only the class itself needs to use it.

If you need to get the enum instance for a given String, use the `valueOf()` method that all enums have.

Comment: Thanks for the help!